# Changing QTreeview checkbox to icon without using stylesheets

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, qtreeview

I wanted to have a `QTreeView` with icons ( which act as a checkbox ) followed by some text from a subclass of `QAbstractItemModel`. I cannot modify or change the structure of this `QAbstractItemModel`.

When I use this `QAbstractItemModel` with `QTreeview`, it shows checkbox followed by some text and performs the intended function required. I just wanted to change this check box to on and off icons.

I found this:- [Customizing the checkboxes of the items of a QTreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827147/customizing-the-checkboxes-of-the-items-of-a-qtreeview)

But, I cannot use stylesheets in my case as the icon I want to use some system icons which are loaded using icon loader which returns a `KIcon` instance ( subclass of `QIcon` ).

What would be the right way of doing this?

I saw this [tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-itemviews-coloreditorfactory-example.html) and tried creating an editor for a checkbox. But, **how should I register editor as `QVariant` does not have `Qt::CheckStateRole` type?**

I tried using `Qt::Int`, but it doesn't works

Comment: Use http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html

Comment: @Amartel can you refer to some tutorial?

Comment: Well, there is a common tutorial on delegates here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes , but, somehow, it doesn't contatins what you need. Though there is an example here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#paint . Overall, you need to overwrite `paint` method and draw whatever you like. I ususally take needed code from Qt's sources.

Comment: @Amartel Thanks, I reimplemented the paint method and its working now.